# What layout does the ActionBar use?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I'm trying to do minor tweaks to the layout of items inside an ActionBar, and hitting a lot of problems. It would help if I knew (or even better: could override!) the layout which Android is using for the ActionBar itself.

(Android's layout system doesn't allow you to fully control layout of "items" direct from the item itself - all the options are enabled/disabled based on what type the parent/container layout has)

So, for instance...

1. try to make a custom ActionView that takes "all remaining space" (because you have no title / don't need a title)
2. ...everything breaks. There are lots of workarounds, all of which have their own bugs (I've tried 3 from SO already, and they all break on different versions of Android / different handsets)
3. this would be TRIVIAL if I could set the ActionBar's layout to "RelativeLayout" and use "layout_toLeftOf" etc

...but the docs don't seem to answer this, nor do they provide a way of setting it. Any ideas? I don't want to have lots of hardcoded, broken code to workaround the API (because it'll make maintaining this app a nightmare :( )

Comment: Have you checked [the grepcode repository](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.1_r1/android/app/ActionBar.java) out yet?

Comment: "I don't want to have lots of hardcoded, broken code to workaround the API" -- that is completely counter to your question. You specifically are asking how to create "hardcoded, broken code". How the action bar lays out its contents is an implementation detail. Asking what that implementation detail is, then planning on relying upon it, will result in "hardcoded, broken code". The only part of your question that might not result in "hardcoded, broken code" would be if you could change the layout of the action bar, which you can't, short of creating your own "action bar" replacement.

Comment: @CommonsWare As noted in the question: I *don't know* if there's a way of changing it; if there is, your comment makes no sense. Also, I don't see how this is "an implementation detail" - since all apps rely upon the behaviour, it's a bit more high-level than that!

Comment: @Asok thanks, I didn't know about grepcode. Unfortunately in this case ... it doesn't seem to help, since the only extra info it contains is details on exactly which gravities are supported for the actionbar itself (Which is useful to know for future, but is only a tiny bit of the problem :()

Comment: @Adam: "Also, I don't see how this is "an implementation detail"" -- today, the action bar could use a `LinearLayout`. Tomorrow, the action bar could use a `RelativeLayout`. Next week, it could implement its own custom container class with its own `onMeasure()` and so forth. So long as the **public API** is satisfied (i.e., `ActionBar`), precisely what mechanics the action bar uses to satisfy that API is up to the developers of the action bar, and those mechanics can change over time.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/)? It's a support library extension that implements action bar on all versions of Android using single API. Also, when it comes to layouts, I often find it very useful to look at the source code. You can find action bar layouts on the very top of the list [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/res/res/layout/).

Answer (score 0):

Load the view hierarchy and then you will be able to see the views that compose any layout.

http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-ui.html